# Isometry between vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$U_1, U_2, U_3, U_4$ are vector spaces and given as

$U_1 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \ | \ x_1 = x_2, x_3 + x_4 = 0 \}$,

$U_2 = \{ f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} \ | \ \exists \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \ \text{such that} \ \forall n \in N : f(n) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2n^2 + \lambda_32^n\}$,

$U_3 = \{ f \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \ | \ f(x) = f(y) \ \text{if} \ x^2 \neq 1 \ \text{and} \ y^2 \neq 1\}$,

$U_4 = \{ f \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \ | \ f(\mathbb{R}) \ \text{has n elements}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$,

where $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ means all mappings from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Check for isomorphisms between the vector spaces.

1. My first observation is: $U_1$ can't be isometric to any other since $dim(U_1) = 4$ and $\ dim (U_2) = dim(U_3) = dim(U_4) = \infty$. So there can only be an isometry between $U_2$, $U_3$ and $U_4$.
2. I'm not sure how to handle the conditions of the spaces (by conditions I mean, for instance, "$f(\mathbb{R}) \ \text{has n elements}$") and what role they play in proofing that there is a function $\phi$ such that $\phi$ is bijective and linear between the two spaces we're looking at. It's hard enough to even think that some of these sets share structures by just looking at them.

EDIT: isometrics and isomorphisms apparently mean different things, my bad.

Comment: We have $\dim U_1=2,\ \dim U_2=\dim U_3=3$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining?

Comment: @Max Could you explain how you came to the conclusion that the spaces $U_2,U_3$ are infinite dimensional?

Comment: @Max Also, an "isometry" implies that we have some sort of norm or metric. Do you instead mean to say that we are checking for *isomorphisms* between the spaces?

Comment: For what it's worth, $U_4$ is the space of all [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function).

Answer (score 0):

HINT : As Berci pointed out, try proving that $U_1, U_2, U_3$ Are $2$ dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.
As for $U_4$, consider a linear function $f$ such as $f(\mathbb{R})$ is finite, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we have by linearity$f(ax)=af(x)$.
Use this to prove that $f$ is necessarily the zero function.

Comment: But Berci said that $U_2$ and $U_3$ are 3 dimensional?